# gnuplot.exe from commandline - starting interactive 3D plot directly?

Tags: gnuplot

I use Gnuplot to plot graphes in my application, I write a command file, call it and then just copy the .png generated.

But now I need to show 3D plots, and they are quite useless if one can not "look around" using the mouse.

So I would like to start wgnuplot.exe and tell it to immediately execute a command (splot "data.dat" with pm3d), so it generates a new window with the interactive 3d plot.

Is this possible? If so, how? When I try it, all I get is a image of the plot, but nothing interactive.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
1.) add "save 'x.plt'" to the plotting command script
2.) call wgnuplot.exe -e "load 'x.plt'"